# IE asks for username password

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer

I am trying to open a url (a report server url) inside an iframe in my ASP.Net application. I am also passing encrypted username/pwd in source url for iframe. It works fine with firefox etc but **in IE 8+ it always asks for username/pwd.**

When I add the report server to the list of allowed sites (Tools > Internet > Options > Privacy),it works fine. But I cannot always except my target users to add the report server url to allowed sites list, so looking for a solution in asp.net/jquery.

Is there any way to change this behaviour ? If I am able to add the report server's url to the allowed sites' list programmatically, even in that case it is ok.

HELP!!!

Comment: is the report server on the same domain? just thinking that it could be that IE behaves that way if your report server is on a different domain?

Comment: No report server is on different domain and application is on different.